# "7 and 5" returns 5?

Tags: python

My code:

```
a = 7
b = 5
print((a and b))
```

Output: 5

Why is the output 5? Doesn't logical operator gives True or False output? Why isnt it raising any errors ?

Comment: Why are you assuming that's a logical operator? It's printing a bitwise operation result... According to what documentation should an error be raised?

Comment: and is used and isn't it a logical operator. Also why is the output 5

Comment: The rule for Python's `and` is: If `a` is "truthy" (seen as true) `b` is returned, `a` otherwise.

Comment: I think that's a good question. One might expect `a and b`  to do something like `bool(a) and (bool)b`, returning either True or False. That's not how the `and` operator works in python though.

Comment: @AndyPreston `7 & 5` would be the bitwise operation (and also results in `5`).

Comment: It has nothing to do with binaries, check `2 and 4` vs `2 & 4` and also `666 and 'YUP'`, for example.

Comment: 7 and 5 was a bad example, FWIW, since the bitwise and logical operator are the same result... If you did `5 and 7`, then that would be a better representation of what you're trying to ask

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the logical operator and returns the first operand if it evaluates to False, otherwise it returns the second operand.

In this case, both a and b are considered True because they are not equal to zero, so the expression (a and b) evaluates to the second operand, which is b with a value of 5.

So the output of print((a and b)) is 5.

Answer (score 2):

It returns the last "truthy" value, see [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)